# SharedPreferences contains method returns always true

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a splash activity which checks if it's the first time the user logs in or not. I am using shared preferences to save if the user already signed in or not. However, after a clean installation of the app (I uninstalled the previous version), I still get an true answer meaning that the it's not the first time of the user to sign in.

This is my if condition to check if the user already signed in:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Login.LOGIN_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if(prefs.contains(Login.REMEMBER_USER) &&
                        prefs.getBoolean(Login.REMEMBER_USER, false)) {

                    NetworkManager.login(SplashActivity.this, SplashActivity.this);
                }
                else{

                    Intent in = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }
```

So the flow is: after uninstallation of the app, and then reinstalling it again, I stop at check condition and it supposed to be false, because it's a first run, however it returns true, and enters the NetworkManager part whereas it should go to the Login part.

Note: It happens only on some devices (Galaxy S6).

What can cause such odd behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mention **`android:allowBackup="true"`** in your Manifest file, your data will be backed up and maintained across uninstalls, which might be undesirable during development.

The default value is true.

You should need to set **`android:allowBackup="false"`** for application data not to be preserved across uninstalls.

Here is the **[documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup)** for the use of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had the following line in my manifest file under application.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
....
</aplication>
```

Once I changed the value to false everything worked.